# Vampires of the Levant

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, religions-and-deities, vampire-the-masquerade

The Levant is the one region that is home to two of the Abrahamic religions: Judaism and Christianity. While most Vampires see themselves as cursed by the Abrahamic god (they carry Caine's curse after all), most of the *Vampire: the Masquerade* lore is discussing the interactions of Christianity and Vampires, for example with the Inquisition. In a little departure of that, the sources on Assamites are discussing the Islamic interaction with the undead.

**However, are there sources that discuss the interactions of Jews with the Kindred?**

---

Please note I'm not looking for personal interpretations of what you think the interactions would be, and I'm especially not looking for people's personal stance. The question is only what the books describe as the interaction of these two groups. That means that you **must** provide sources, best with page numbers. Unsourced answers will be treated as opinions!

And I want to remind you to be very civil. Or to quote [a (former) mod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132639/30306) on a similarly contentious question:

> You (collective you, site members) will use comments only to ask for clarification on the question and you will use answers only to answer the question posed. We have no patience for shenanigans on this site so be on your best behavior on this question.
> – mxyzplk  Sep 29 '18 at 17:57

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### State of Grace

[This 2002 sourcebook](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/State_of_Grace) details the interactions of the Kindred with real-world religions, with Judaism explicitly included. A lot of word count goes to explaining just what Judaism entails to an audience that might be unfamiliar with the faith, but pp. 45-55 and 67-71 do address some areas of interest: difficulties that Jewish vampires have reconciling their condition with their practice, and links to Lilith and her cults.

Comment: @Trish Sure. Make no mistake — this is pretty meager; when they talk about running out of ideas near the end of Revised, this is the kind of thing they mean. If you cut out everything that could be found in a basic Wikipedia search on Jewishness, you get maybe a page or two of specific World of Darkness connected lore or story seeds.

Answer (score 7):

I’ve used a few online resources, including the White Wolf wiki, but it seems there aren’t many sources that deal with this question specifically. Most of those that do are for the Dark Ages era. But here’s what I found.

### Modern Nights

*Beckett’s Jyhad Diary* has a chapter (“The Madness of Jerusalem”) set in Jerusalem, but it seems mostly to be about the possible presence of a Malkavian methuselah near the city, whose influence “intensifies religious fervour”.

*Clanbook: Assamite* for the revised edition includes a small amount of information about the Leopards of Zion, a small splinter group of the clan who are predominantly (but not exclusively) Jewish, and operate mainly in Jerusalem.

*The Hunters Hunter II* has a short section about The Judges, a Jewish group of hunters organised in a manner similar to the Order of Leopold and now based mainly in Jerusalem. Many of their battles are with vampires. (pg. 154-155)

The Tremere clanbooks list the clan’s houses, and include House Hashem, who are dedicated to the study of Kabbalah as a magical tool. It’s suggested many of their members would be Jewish, but doesn’t discuss how they deal with their condition in terms of faith.

### Dark Ages: Vampire

*Jerusalem by Night* is focused on the conflict between Islam and Christianity, so there doesn’t seem to be much about Judaism in there.

The V20 Dark Ages book details *Derech Chaim*, the Path of Life, a path of morality for the Road of Heaven based on the tenets of Judaism. It is suggested that it is mainly followed by vampires who were Jewish in life. (pg. 119-120)

Comment: Would you have page numbers possibly?

Comment: @Trish I can find them for some of these, yes - I’ll add them in!

Comment: @Trish I’ll need to dig out my copy of the Assamite clanbook to find those page numbers; I was able to find the others I’ve added via the wiki.

Comment: Vampires are immortal unless killed, right? It seems entirely possible that some of the crusader and jihadi vampires from Jerusalem by Night are still around in the modern nights.

Comment: @nick012000 oh absolutely - but from what I can tell the book has little to say about Jewish vampires, so it doesn’t really answer the question.